# UNET:how to get each network start position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking

I'm really new to unity and specially to unity networking system , So my problem is :

I'm devoloping a card game in which i need to get the network start position in scripting so i can instantiate my cards . I found in unity scripting API the following :
[enter link description here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkManager-startPositions.html)

So I made a script in which i did this :

```
public class CardSpawner : NetworkBehaviour
{

public List<GameObject> Cards;



void Start()
{


    distributeCards (Cards);
}

[Server]
public void distributeCards (List<GameObject> list){

    Transform startPositionTransform;
    Vector2 position, finalPosition;
    NetworkManager NetM;
    List<Transform> startPositionsList;

    Vector2 Increment = new Vector2 (1.41f, 0f);
    NetM = GetComponent<NetworkManager> ();
    for ( int i = 1; i<5 ;i++){
        for (int j=0; j<8; j++) {

            GameObject CurrentGameObject = list[Random.Range(0,list.Count)];

            list.Remove(CurrentGameObject);

            switch (i){
            case 1:
                startPositionsList = NetM.startPositions ;
                startPositionTransform = startPositionsList[3];
                position =startPositionTransform.position;
                finalPosition = position + j * Increment;
                Network.Instantiate (CurrentGameObject, finalPosition, Quaternion.identity, 4);
                break;
            case 2:
                //position = startPositionsList [1];
                //finalPosition = position + j * Increment;
                //Network.Instantiate (CurrentGameObject, position, Quaternion.identity, 4);
                break;
            case 3:
                //position = startPositionsList [2];
                //finalPosition = position + j * Increment;
                //Network.Instantiate (CurrentGameObject, position, Quaternion.identity, 4);
                break;
            case 4:
                //position = startPositionsList [3];
                //finalPosition = position + j * Increment;
                //Network.Instantiate (CurrentGameObject, position, Quaternion.identity, 4);
                break;

            }


        }

    }
}

}
```

but i get this error in the console while playing my scene  :

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an 
object
CardSpawner.distributeCards (System.Collections.Generic.List`1 list) (at 
Assets/Scripts/CardSpawner.cs:39)
CardSpawner.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/CardSpawner.cs:17)
```

I don't see from where this error come from but any advice will be appreciated .thanks for your time.